# Setting custom levels of atomicity on transactions and event driven / streaming real time data.

Tags: c#, real-time, real-time-data

I am a C# developer and have a lot of experience with C# and SQL, but have an interest in SingalR, and real time data and JSON store/NOSQL and how it is being used.

I would like to build an application to highlight text as it is read, when a user mouses over the text with the cursor or moves through the text with the caret, and share where people have read up to.

I don't want to commit a change to a database on every word, but probably would like to at the end of sentences or paragraphs, or after a period of time. But I would like to share the data between users in real time. And when the information has been committed to the database I'd like to make that highlighted text a slightly darker color.

So my question is, is there a technology that I could use to access/store and share data with events on the data pushing changes to the client, without polling a database. But also let me also establish rules on the data around the levels of atomicity for the different types of transactions?

What I am interested in seeing if I can avoid is having to build two models of the data, and syncing them. I want to just find some technology to handle the syncing the atomic and real time data, and I can just focus on setting the rules about when the data needs to be recorded to the transnational database.

Comment: there's lots, but looking for resources is offtopic, but you may want to consider Akka, Rx, or Orleans

Comment: I am not aware of any. But given you are building real time app some generics solution will probably just cost you performance you don't have the luxury of losing. You might want to check [this](https://www.ageofascent.com/blog/) out I know they are doing insane numbers performance wise.